# Trying to do a simple calculation with a button

Tags: javascript, html, calculation

For a project, I'm trying to make a type of calculator. Where I'm having trouble with is changing my button value to what I want the calculation output to be

here is a small portion of my html because it's a big table but I'm trying to make a button like this one for all of them...

```
<td><span>2</span></td>
<td><input type="text" id="round[2][score]" ></td>
<td><input type="text" id="round[2][rating]" ></td>
<td><input type="text" id="round[2][slope]" ></td>
<td><input type="button" onclick="calculate1()" id="round[2][handicap]" Value="Press"></td>
                    </tr>
```

here is the function I made for the calculations:

```
function calculate1() 
{

    round2score = document.getElementById('round[2][score]').value;
    round2rating = document.getElementById('round[2][rating]').value;
    round2slope = document.getElementById('round[2][slope]').value;
    document.getElementById("round[2][handicap]").innerHTML = round2score - round2rating;

}
```

again, my goal is to change the "press" to the calculated value.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You may also wish to peruse [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow). A relevant entry: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using InnerHTML, to set the button value use the following:

```
    document.getElementById("round[2][handicap]").value = String(round2score - round2rating);
```

This will set the value of the button, which is the text displayed.

Comment: No worries Sarah, if you could mark this question as answered that would be greatly appreciated :)